# Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed in Safari

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari, http-headers, cors

The following code looks up a user's city from their IP address.

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      var message = '';

      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://freegeoip.net/json',
        type: "GET",
        success: function(result) {
          message = result.city + ' - ';
        }
      })
      .always(function(){
        $('.location span').html(message);
      });

    });
```

It works find except in Safari where it gives the error...

> Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Headers" Failed
>   to load resource: Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have same problem. Have you solved this issue?

Comment: No, we tried another service.